# How to trigger event only after user stopped triggering events

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3

How to trigger event only after user stopped using his mouse? Because I don't want to call my ajax during the zoom (for example, 6 zoom-ins would trigger 6 events, but I need only 1 event, when zoom-in is done)

This function delays the execution, nevertheless, it still executes all events...

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      myfunction());
    }, 3000);
  });
```

Comment: There probably is no such event, but you could clear a timeout on each mousemove, zoom or whatever, and if it's not cleared the user did'nt do anything for 3 seconds, and the function executes etc.

Comment: That solved my issue! Pretty much each time trigger is triggered, I do this: `clearInterval(trigerFunctionVar); trigerFunctionVar=null;` And then add new Interval to `trigerFunctionVar`. Works like a charm! Please add as the answer, so I could choose it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem:

Each time trigger is triggered, I do this: `clearInterval(trigerFunctionVar);` `trigerFunctionVar=null;` And then add new Interval to `trigerFunctionVar`

Answer (score 0):

Could you use offsetLeft and offsetTop to calculate the mouse cursors x and y positions then execute your event after they haven't changed for a short period of time?

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastTriggeredTime;  
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      //set last Triggered Time to now (user is still zooming)
      lastTriggeredTime = (new Date()).getTime();
      myfunction());
    }, 1000);
  });
var myfunction = function(){
  if(lastTriggeredTime + 3000 < (new Date()).getTime()){
    //3 seconds has elapsed since last center_changed event got fired.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions :

```
var cpt = 0;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function ()
{
    cpt++;
    var cpt2 = cpt;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        if (cpt == cpt2) console.log("Task is executed if it is the last event since 3sec");
    }, 3000);
});
```

OR

Use event « idle » !
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html